# Detecting changes to the clipboard on Android

Tags: android, detection

Is it possible to detect when an Android user uses the **copy** and/or **cut** functionality?

I have a client who's idea pretty much depends on being able to call a method inside the app whenever a user copies or cuts out a piece of text or an image, no matter whether the user is actually inside the app or not (though the app would be running in the background).

My initial guess would be no, but you never know. I haven't been able to find any clear information about it, so thought I should ask.

Comment: You lost me at `cuts out a piece of.. an image`. How? Where? Code?

Comment: @user3249477 "a piece of text" or "an image" as in when a user selects some text, or an image, and clicks "Copy" or "Cut" to save it to the clipboard. Thought that was pretty clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect when an Android user uses the copy and/or cut functionality?

Not exactly. You can listen for changes in the clipboard using [`ClipboardManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html). However:

1. Changes in the clipboard do not always imply "copy and/or cut" operations
2. You can only listen for such changes while your process is running

Comment: All right, but I suppose that's good enough. Do you know if it's possible to add an event listener for it, or would I have to write a polling script?

Comment: @Tom: You can register a listener on `ClipboardManager`. The problem is that [on Android 4.3, having such a listener will crash the apps that try to use the clipboard](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58043), which will make your app unpopular. And [I am hoping the listener is better secured someday](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59073).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :) Hopefully this is solved in Android 4.4, though... will do some digging.